# AngularJS Custom Form Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to make a field on a form valid by using the $valid class. I have the below HTML and JS code but even though the JS seems to work by modifying code editors, it doesn't validate the HTML. It doesn't seem to make it so $valid does anything but become true if the field has any text in it.

```
<input name="user" ng-model="user" ng-controller="SearchController"  placeholder="User ID" required><br>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="searchForm.user.$dirty && searchForm.user.$invalid">A valid user ID is required.</span>
```

and

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', []);

searchApp.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var users = ['11', '22', '33', '44']
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function idValidation(value) {
                if (users.includes(value)) {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(idValidation);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The JS logic seems to work, but the HTML is not working correctly.

Comment: Why don't you utilize HTML5 `input` validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a few minor errors in your code's logic to make this function correctly.

What you are attempting to do is create a [custom validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation). Your directive is using a `$parser` function, which is intended to parse a model's value for display. What you really want to be doing is working with a `$validators` function.

So, you would want to do something along the following:

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', []);

searchApp.directive('validUser', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var users = ['11', '22', '33', '44']
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            mCtrl.$validators.charE = function (value) {
                return users.includes(value)
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

What happens is anytime the `ngModel` changes, it will run the value through the validators and determine if they are valid or invalid and automatically set `ng-invalid-{name}` or `ng-valid-{name}` (in this example, `ng-invalid-charE` and `ng-valid-charE`).

You can than use [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) to define your errors and they will show and hide as appropriate based on the validity.

Your `ngController` should more likely be a directive that adds the validator and your controller to contain the entire Search functionality/form HTML and be above your input to define your scope. Changing it to a directive would mean you'd remove `ngController` from the input and add an attribute for `valid-user` (as I've updated the name).

Comment: How would I go about making it so the input would stay invalid until it is valid within the directive? Currently the only thing that makes it invalid is when I have the required tag there.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `$validators` function I've added here will accomplish that for you. Every time the input changes, it reruns the validations. If it is invalid, it stays invalid. If it becomes valid, it will add `ng-valid-charE` to the classes and remove the error messages.